# How to Decode the &amp; from a URL so that header() works (urldecode not working)

Tags: php, header, decoding, urldecode

I have the following URL: `$url = 'http://mysite.com/?p=welcome&amp;x=1&amp;y=2';`

I need to decode it so that `header("Location: $url");` actually works.

However, using `urldecode($url)` is not working because it's **not** decoding the `&amp;` -> `&` and so the browser is getting redirected to `http://mysite.com/?p=welcome&amp;x=1&amp;y=2` which fails.

I need it to decode so that it looks like:  `http://mysite.com/?p=welcome&x=1&y=2`

How do I do that?

Comment: In case the above is NOT a typo: it should be `header("Location: $url")` - note the `:`.

Comment: @Marc B:  Thanks, was just a typo here, not in my script.  Just fixed it above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try with [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('http://mysite.com/?p=welcome&amp;x=1&amp;y=2');
//"http://mysite.com/?p=welcome&x=1&y=2"
```

Comment: What the difference between `htmlspecialchars_decode` you are recommending and the `html_entity_decode` everyone else is recommending?  Which one should I use?

Comment: @Programmer `html_entity_decode` is for heavy weight entity decoding, such as turning `&larr;` into `←`. `htmlspecialchars_decode` is only for unescaping escaped html, it decodes only the characters necessary to escape html. `htmlspecialchars_decode` is semantically more correct one to use here imo.

Comment: Perfect fix.  Had an odd header("location:")  issue where sometimes I was seeing & being turned into &amp; ... used $ref = htmlspecialchars_decode($ref); to clean the variable and FIXED.  thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`&amp;` isn't URL encoded (aka [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), but is an HTML entity. URL-encoded it would look like `%26`.

Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 5):

`&amp;` isn't url-encoded. You need use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 4):

I'd try this:

```
$url = html_entity_decode($url);
header("Location: $url");
```

taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

I'd do so 'cause your `$url` is not url-encoded but html-encoded, with html special characters replaced with the corresponding html entity.